# Jquery Slider broken in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, slider, anythingslider

I can't seem to figure out/debug the jquery slider in IE7. It is throwing an error on line 680 of the anythingslider.js file saying that [2] is null. Any idea what's going on?

Here's the page:
http://www.baltimoreschoolofmusic.org

Thanks!

Comment: It might be that IE7 thinks that you're referencing an element that's beyond the array. Then again, it's IE7. Nice website, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I also get an error on line 13 within your page rather than the js plugin. I'm testing on IE7 on WinXP.
Line 13 error:
`Object doesn't support this property or method.`

which is:
`$("#sildes").slides();`

The error you are referencing on line 608 and another on 619 which is similar in that there is an if statement within the array node:

`d[base.dir] = -base.panelSize[(o.infiniteSlides && base.pages > 1) ? page : page - 1][2];`

How deep does the array go? 
Sorry, I've added this as a comment, but I'm not at my 50 rec points yet. And, I agree, IE7 should be retired!

**How about this: in your head you are calling `slides.js` -- and that's throwing a 404.**

Answer (score 0):

Just don't support IE7. That's the easy answer. Do a check to see if the browser is IE7, and then just replace the slider with an image. Users of IE are generally distracted by sliders anyway, and on the whole dislike interactivity. If they wanted a beautiful viewing/interactive experience, they wouldn't be using IE7.

Seriously, you're wasting your time that will not assist your aims of user/client conversion even 1%. This is not a coding answer, it is a marketing and commercially based answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that IE7 doesn't seem to recognize any content inside the `UL` if each `LI` is wrapped in a link:

```
<ul id="slider">
  <a href="slide-page.php">
    <li>
      <img src="myimage.jpg">
      <h2>Header</h2>
      <p>text.</p>
    </li>
  </a>

  <!-- more li's wrapped in a's -->

</ul>
```

so, move the links inside the `LI` instead:

```
<ul id="slider">
  <li>
    <a href="slide-page.php">
      <img src="myimage.jpg">
      <h2>Header</h2>
      <p>text.</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <!-- more li's -->

</ul>
```

I tried to make [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ycUB6/4066/), but jsFiddle doesn't want to seem to run in IE7.... oh well.